# Parameterized Query Works but do I need the two lines?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic, parameters

The code below works fine I just wanted to ask if I take out 2 lines of code the code still works the same but should I take it out or keep it and what does it do ?

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
        ' OPEN DATABASE
        dim objConn,objRS,objTRS,objUnit

'----Do I need this ? ----> Const adCmdText = &H0001

        Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
        objConn.ActiveConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MSSQLSrv;Database=DbTest;UID=blablabala;PWD=blablabala"

'----Do I need this ? ----> objConn.CommandType = adCmdText

        strQuery = "SELECT USERNAME,PASSWORD from CUSTOMERS where EMAIL=?"
        objConn.CommandText=strQuery 
        objConn.Parameters(0) = Request.QueryString("email")
        SET objRS = objConn.execute(strQuery)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 1 and 2 are working together

```
Const adCmdText = 1                  'Evaluate as a textual definition
objConn.CommandType = adCmdText    ' Evaluate as textual definition, not stored procedure
```

The CommandType can be a Stored Procdure. You can set/define your own way directly through the SP and then call (Using the SqlCommand) so there is no need to define UserDefinedFunction.

See http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_comm_commandtype.asp for the complete listing of all the CommandTypeEnum Values

Hope this helps...

Comment: Ahh got it, The CommandType property sets or returns a CommandTypeEnum value that defines the type of the Command object. Default is adCmdUnknown. 
If you do not specify the type, ADO will need to contact the provider to determine the type of the command. However, if you do specify the type, ADO will be able to process the command faster. So I don't need it, thx

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need it. `Text` is the default value.